# Web site hosted on Heroku is not available only on IPhone

Tags: iphone, node.js, heroku

Nodejs app is deployed on Heroku (Europe). When I open it from my IPhone 4 (IOS 7) site is not available (response time ends) NOTE: sometimes it's available.

When I launch it locally everything is working ok. 
On android and PC everything is working ok.

http://www.happyscan.me/ 
http://happyscan.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Oleg, have you find any solution since october? I'm experiencing the same thing happening on a new project of mine.

Comment: nope, it's working now

Comment: I guess this is due to the cache issue in Safari, affecting both iOS and OS X. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811286/nodejs-express-cache-and-304-status-code