# Nodejs Express, cache issue, 304 vs 200 headers

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express application, my route file has the following code:

java.ejs

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var handle_database = require('../db');

var drvArray = [];
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = "SELECT qte FROM drivers";
    handle_database(query, true, function (resp) {
        drvArray.push({
            "drivers" : resp
        });
        res.render('java', {
            drivers : JSON.stringify(drvArray[0])
        });
    });
});
```

When I run my server and go to the view file java.js that has this code :

```
<%= drivers %>
```

I get this output : `{"drivers":[{"qte":"2000"}]}`

and the output in the console is : GET /java 200 50.030 ms - 982.

Now when I edit the entry in my database and make it 3000 I get in the view the old result 2000 and not 3000 and the output in console is :

```
GET /java 304 8.562 ms - -
```

If I restart the server I get the new correct value 3000 but 200 as header.

So how can I deal with that and have always the correct value displayed?

Comment: Any answers please ?

Comment: This seems to be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811286/nodejs-express-cache-and-304-status-code