# Sometimes GET returns 304 instead of 200

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js and mongodb.

I seem to be receiving a 200 sometimes, and a 304 not modified other times.

```
router.get('/add-to-bag/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.bag.push(req.params.id);
    res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't... that not be a GET request, but instead POST or PUT? you're performing an action, not getting info

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't be sure what stack you're using to create the app. It looks like you're using Express.js to do routing. However, I can tell you why you're getting a 304.

From Wikipedia:

> 304 Not Modified (RFC 7232)
> Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match. In such case, there is no need to retransmit the resource since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy.[24]

A 304 means "hey, remember the last answer I sent you? It hasn't changed", and hence your browser would replay the last response it received from cache, without data transmission ever having taken place.

This means that your data *is* being added. But since it's the exact same data in the bag, instead of giving a 200 with the exact same data again, the server just issues a 304.

**BTW**: Your API isn't Restful. I'd recommend using `POST` to create new records instead of issuing a `GET` to a different URL. I recommend reading up on REST API design. It's pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Very useful and detailed answer. Thanks bro!

Comment: depending on version of Chrome, checking "Disable cache" in the inspector can preventing sending the `If-None-Match` header with requests

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** Use a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request.

`GET` requests should be used for *getting* things. A `GET` request should not affect the state of the application (i.e. of the server).

In your case, adding an item to the shopping bag is clearly a *modification of the state of the server*.

If you're not convinced, [check out this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188861)

> A GET is defined in this way in the HTTP protocol. It is supposed to be idempotent and safe.

If you use a `POST` request, not only will it fix you 304 issue, but it will also prevent some other possible bugs later on. (And it will be more correct.)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try by disabling etag?

```
app.disable('etag');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',` to my headers was able to bypass the 304 issue I was having. Seen in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942074/why-is-http-get-returning-304-error#answer-41948654)