# How to fix express app that's not logging anything

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to place some data I need for my express application in cookies. I'm trying to see what's inside my request like that:

```
import session from 'express-session';
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecretString',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2},
  store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection, ttl: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60})
}));

app.get('/zzz', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req session', req.session);
  if(typeof req.session !== 'undefined') {
    res.json(req);
  }
});
```

The problem is everytime I make get request to /zzz, the only thing I see in the console is 'GET /zzz 304 some miliseconds - -'. And that's it.
I'm making the request using axios like that:

```
export const getUser = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      '/zzz'
    );
    console.log('RESPONSE', response);
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: 'error' });
  }
};
```

And in the response I get there's .....well you can see it in the picture.[image: response in the browser]

Now the funny part. I'm saving data in cookies while signing user in on completely different route like that.

```
req.session.user = {
    user: req.user.email,
    isAdmin: false,
    token
  };
  req.session.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.json(req.session.user);
  });
};
```

And the funny thing is that in this place I can both log in the console my 'req.session' and later see it in browser.....
Does anyone have idea what have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but some thoughts: (1) it looks like your response is that of some HTML. Is that what you expected..? (2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789363/3814251 has a helpful explanation of what a 304 means. (TLDR, it's the server telling the browser to look at its cache.)

Comment: I expect to find an js object in my response.

Comment: How can I check out browser cache for specific request?