# How to 'solve' 304 statusCode in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-304, morgan

Briefly, I have created a server using nodeJS. I have installed 'morgan' for the logger. When I render my front-end everything works, my website can be accessed, RU (registered users) can book, ...
However the main problem is that I am getting 304 statusCodes in my terminal.

is the problem even fixed in the backend or is the problem related to the browser (using chrome btw)? How can I solve this problem to get 200 statusCode?

if everything is working, then I should have received 200 statusCode. I have looked a lot and still haven't found a solution that works. There is a question around this in stack over flow which dates back years ago ([NodeJS/express: Cache and 304 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811286/nodejs-express-cache-and-304-status-code)). The answer(s) given which is app.disable('etag'); (or the updated version: app.set('etag', false);) or using app.router which is now deprecated does not work for me.

Also when I clear cache from my browser and run my server again, I get 200 statusCode for the first time but then the second time (onwards) when nothing is changed and I refresh, I get 304 for the statusCode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tested ```app.disable('etag')``` and it works, so did you really tried it?.

Comment: I don't understand why 304 is problem for you, etag helps browsers to cache responses by sending response hash in header.  [learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)

Comment: @bogdanoff regarding your first comment, yes I wrote it in my app.js which is my server script. I also placed it at different lines to see whether the position of this middleware will make a difference, but still didn't work. For the second comment, I was with the impression that we should aim to get 2xx status codes (?) So, I wanted to do so and after reading several pages did not find a practical solution for this goal (or the solutions found did not work for me).