# Mongo database responds with 304 not modified upon deployment possible catch all error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, deployment, mern

The app works fine in development, and all data is returned as expected through the frontend.

However, when I run it in production I get an error of 304 and html is returned. This persists when I disable cache.

If I query this route on my server the expected json data is returned. https://two2062023.onrender.com/api/hotels/countByCity?cities=berlin,madrid,london

However, it is not returned directly within the app on the frontend. I noticed in my network the path seems to be missing the /api.

I have been told this may be a catch-all on all paths to ensure client side routing works.

Can anyone offer further advice?

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?

**Folder structure**

[image: folder structure]

**mongodb settings **

[image: mongo settings]

**client index.js **

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.js";
import usersRoute from "./routes/users.js";
import hotelsRoute from "./routes/hotels.js";
import roomsRoute from "./routes/rooms.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import path from 'path';


const app = express();
dotenv.config();

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB.")
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected!");
});

//middlewares
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.disable('etag')

// we use this middlware because by defauly you cannot send json unless you use this middleware

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoute);
app.use("/api/hotels", hotelsRoute);
app.use("/api/rooms", roomsRoute);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const errorStatus = err.status || 500;
    const errorMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong!";
    return res.status(errorStatus).json({
        success: false,
        status: errorStatus,
        message: errorMessage,
        stack: err.stack,
    });
});



const __dirname = path.resolve();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {

    //set static folder


    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')))

    //any route that is not one of the listed api routes above, will be redircted to index.html

    app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')))
    console.log('this has just run!!!')

} else {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Api is running')
    })
}



const port = process.env.PORT || 8800;

app.listen(port, () => {
    connect();
    console.log(` server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}. Connected to server at port ${port}.`);
    console.log(` this is your ${path.resolve()} `)
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)


});
```

**client FeaturedProperties.jsx **

```
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import "./featuredProperties.css";

const FeaturedProperties = () => {
        const {
            data,
            loading,
            error
        } = useFetch("/hotels?featured=true&limit=4");
        console.log(data)

        return ( <
            div className = "fp" > {
                loading ? (
                    "Loading"
                ) : ( <
                        > {
                            data && Array.isArray(data).data.map((item) => ( <
                                    div className = "fpItem"
                                    key = {
                                        item._id && item._id
                                    } >
                                    <
                                    img src = {
                                        item.photos && item.photos[0]
                                    }
                                    alt = ""
                                    className = "fpImg" /
                                    >
                                    <
                                    span className = "fpName" > {
                                        item.name && item.name
                                    } < /span> <
                                    span className = "fpCity" > {
                                        item.city && item.city
                                    } < /span> <
                                    span className = "fpPrice" > Starting from $ {
                                        item.cheapestPrice && item.cheapestPrice
                                    } < /span> {
                                        item.rating && < div className = "fpRating" >
                                            <
                                            button > {
                                                item.rating && item.rating
                                            } < /button> <
                                            span > Excellent < /span> <
                                            /div>} <
                                            /div>
                                    ))
                            } <
                            />
                        )
                    } <
                    /div>
            );
        };

        export default FeaturedProperties;
```

**client useFetch hook **

```
import {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url);
                setData(res.data);
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    const reFetch = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            setData(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

    return {
        data,
        loading,
        error,
        reFetch
    };
};

export default useFetch;
```

** server hotel routes **

```
import express from "express";
import {
    countByCity,
    countByType,
    createHotel,
    deleteHotel,
    getHotel,
    getHotelRooms,
    getHotels,
    updateHotel,
} from "../controllers/hotel.js";
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";
import {
    verifyAdmin
} from "../utils/verifyToken.js"
const router = express.Router();

//CREATE
router.post("/", verifyAdmin, createHotel);

//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyAdmin, updateHotel);
//DELETE
router.delete("/:id", verifyAdmin, deleteHotel);
//GET

router.get("/find/:id", getHotel);
//GET ALL

router.get("/", getHotels);
router.get("/countByCity", countByCity);
router.get("/countByType", countByType);
router.get("/room/:id", getHotelRooms);

export default router;
```

** server hotel controllers **

```
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";
import Room from "../models/Room.js";


// this is async because we need to connect to mongo database first
//we handle our errors using express middlewares instead of
//catch(err) { res.status(500).json(err)}
//req can also be a query but here we are taking the request body


export const createHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body);

    try {
        const savedHotel = await newHotel.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedHotel);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};

// new true options means updateHotel returns the updated data & not the old data

export const updateHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const updatedHotel = await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id, {
                $set: req.body
            }, {
                new: true
            }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedHotel);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
export const deleteHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await Hotel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json("Hotel has been deleted.");
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
export const getHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json(hotel);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};



///within the Hotel.find() 
//if we use Hotel.find(req.query) it will return hotels that meet that query
//an example of a query is /hotels?featured= true
//we can take .limit on by Hotel.find(req.query).limit(req.query.limit)
//an example of a query is /hotels?featured= true?limit=3

//db.collection.find(query, projection, options)
// query selector $lt Matches values that are less than a specified value.
// $gt Matches values that are greater than a specified value.

export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        min,
        max,
        ...others
    } = req.query;
    try {
        const hotels = await Hotel.find({
            ...others,
            cheapestPrice: {
                $gt: min | 1,
                $lt: max || 999
            },
        }).limit(req.query.limit);
        res.status(200).json(hotels);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};


//it is req.query because the route is a query string i.e. /countbyCities?
//The cities query is split into an array using the split function

//the function returns the individual elements of the array 
//& then uses the MONGODB count function & asks for a count of each individual city


export const countByCity = async (req, res, next) => {
    const cities = req.query.cities.split(",");
    try {
        const list = await Promise.all(
            cities.map((city) => {
                return Hotel.countDocuments({
                    city: city
                });
            })
        );
        res.status(200).json(list);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};




//as we have a set number of types, we do not need to use req.params or req.query

export const countByType = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const hotelCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({
            type: "hotel"
        });
        const apartmentCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({
            type: "apartment"
        });
        const resortCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({
            type: "resort"
        });
        const villaCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({
            type: "villa"
        });
        const cabinCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({
            type: "cabin"
        });

        res.status(200).json([{
                type: "hotel",
                count: hotelCount
            },
            {
                type: "apartments",
                count: apartmentCount
            },
            {
                type: "resorts",
                count: resortCount
            },
            {
                type: "villas",
                count: villaCount
            },
            {
                type: "cabins",
                count: cabinCount
            },
        ]);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};

//promise.all takes an iterable of promises and returns as a single promise.
//here we are returning all rooms that match the id. Each Rooom.findbyid is an individual promise


export const getHotelRooms = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.id);
        const list = await Promise.all(
            hotel.rooms.map((room) => {
                return Room.findById(room);
            })
        );
        res.status(200).json(list)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
```

** server hotel model **

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const HotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    distance: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    photos: {
        type: [String],
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
    },

    // it is an array because it is going to include room ids
    rooms: {
        type: [String],
    },
    cheapestPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    featured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
});

export default mongoose.model("Hotel", HotelSchema)
```

Comment: Just try to clear the cache, and hard reload the browser. And could please post the backend code as well?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried as you suggested and the problem persists. I have now posted some backend code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811286/nodejs-express-cache-and-304-status-code

Comment: Thank you. I have put it in my middleware as per below but it still is responding the same. Should I position it elsewhere in my code. 
```app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.disable('etag');```

Comment: After deploying still you are getting the same issue? Im sorry, I was bit stuck in my another ques :( that's why I couldn't reply to you.

Comment: Yes, sadly I am.  I feel like it is probably a cache issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please me right now to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76533929/how-to-select-multiple-hearts-as-per-user-will-select-in-react-js) ? Actually  I am stuck in my question that's why I couldn't  help you here :(

Comment: I think someone has posted an answer. Did that work?

Comment: I asked them to provide a demo so I could properly understand because the codesandbox is using by another user and it is MicroVM so I couldn't so any edit using of that answer if someone left only then I can do.

Comment: Hi, I get to work on that posted answer. Thank you so much for helping me. I think I could help you now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my `package.json` file in the frontend. It routed to `localhost:8800/api` during development so it all worked.

In production, `api` was no longer included in the `axios` requests from the frontend.
I adjusted the `axios` routes to include `api/hotels/etc....` and they now work fine.